# Can I mark variables as transient so they won't be pickled?

Tags: python, pickle

Let's say I have a class:

```
class Thing(object):
    cachedBar = None

    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def bar(self):
        if not self.cachedBar:
            self.cachedBar = doSomeIntenseCalculation()
        return self.cachedBar
```

To get bar some intense calculation, so I cache it in memory to speed things up.

However, when I pickle one of these classes I don't want `cachedBar` to be pickled.

**Can I mark cachedBar as volatile / transient / not picklable?**

Comment: You could find the expensive functions and memoize them.

Comment: @Nick That's exactly what he's doing, only he wants to make sure the memo doesn't get pickled along with the object.

Comment: Luke, I figured that there would be sub-functions that would be easier to memoize.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [Pickle documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle.html#pickle-inst), you can provide a method called `__getstate__()`, which returns something representing the state you want to have pickled (if it isn't provided, `pickle` uses `thing.__dict__`). So, you can do something like this:

```
class Thing:
      def __getstate__(self):
            state = dict(self.__dict__)
            del state['cachedBar']
            return state
```

This doesn't have to be a dict, but if it is something else, you need to also implement `__setstate__(state)`.

Comment: One could generalize this facility using custom data descriptors that would store things under `self._transient`, and then `__getstate__` could be written just once to ignore `_transient`. But that's likely overkill unless the code base is doing this *a lot*.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, dude! I kept on googling for something to attach or denote against actual variables to exclude them, I didn't think to look for a method to include them :S

Comment: Awesome! With `json.dump` this requires an explicit `json.dump(self.__getstate__(), f)`

Answer (score 3):

Implement [`__getstate__`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) to return only what parts of an object to be pickled