# How should I serialize game objects containing pygame surfaces?

Tags: python, pygame

To easily save the game state of my game, I tend to serialize my `game` object which contains all game entities (a.k.a. actors).

A common problem I encounter is that you can't pickle [pygame surfaces](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), so if your actor class looks like this:

```
class Actor(object):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self._image = kwargs['image']
      self.pos = kwargs['pos']
      ...

  def act(self):
      ...

  def draw(self, surface):
      surface.blit(self._image, self.pos)
```

you can't just pickle it with the [python pickle/cpickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module.

How to get around this?

Comment: I thought there was a way to 'blacklist' members, so pickle skips them. Can you do that and pickle a tuple or string that represents the image filepath or id, that you use to load it?

Comment: @monkey Yes, [you could do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313421/can-i-mark-variables-as-transient-so-they-wont-be-pickled). If your game is quite small, this is a sensible approach. But if game gets larger and larger, you want to move the functionality of loading resources to a seperate class anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to try to serialze the surfaces, but to remove them from your game/game entities and use a technique like [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) e.g. to obtain them again, after restoring the game state.

So instead of passing the surface directly to the entity, pass it an object that is responsible for storing/retrieving the surface:

```
class Actor(object):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self._image_getter = kwargs['image_getter']
    self.pos = kwargs['pos']
    ...

  def draw(self, surface):
    surface.blit(self._image_getter(), self.pos)
```

The `image getter` could look like this:

```
class SurfaceCapsule (object):

    def __init__(self, resource_manager, key):
        self._res = resource_manager
        self._key = key

    def __call__(self):
        return self._res[self._key]
```

Note that I use a class here, since a method itself would also not be pickable.

Instead of creating your entities like this:

```
actor = Actor(image=resource_manager[key])
```

you would create them like this:

```
actor = Actor(image_getter=SurfaceCapsule(resource_manager, key))
```

where `resource_manager` would be the object managing all surfaces of your game.

```
class RessourceManager(dict):

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # implement lazy loading if you want, or load all images at startup
        # load surface is necessary, cache it, and return it

    def __load_surface_by_key(key):
        # load stuff
```

Before saving your game state, you have to `clear()` it, and then you can happilly serialize it.

---

Another way is to outsource the drawing of the actors, so you would just store an identifier to the surfaces in your actors.

```
class Actor(object):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.image_key = kwargs['image_key']
```

and in your game class:

```
def draw(self):
    for actor in self._actors:
        self._screen.blit(resource_manager[actor.image_key], actor.pos)
```

but this is somewhat cumbersome if your actors use more than one surface to represent theirself.