# Is it possible to create in Python a similar behaviour to a class member persistency state, as done with Java 'transient' keyword?

Tags: java, python, json, serialization, persistence

I have a python data class that contains fields that I do not want to be persisted/saved/serialized (excluded as well from `pickle.dump()`/`json.dump()`/etc).

What I'm looking for can be best explained as something similar to Java `transient`, were I can mark a class member as `transient` and that member will be excluded from any persistency or serialization of that class object without any additional boilerplate code.

I've found this similar question: [Can I mark variables as transient so they won't be pickled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313421/can-i-mark-variables-as-transient-so-they-wont-be-pickled) but it only address pickle.

Is there a pythonic way of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll note, you have to write your own encoder to make your object JSON serializable.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a thing in Python simply because there is no consistent method of serialisation in the first place. As your linked question demonstrates, pickle uses `__getstate__`, but JSON and yaml serializers don't necessarily. You would need to override whatever code is doing the actual serialisation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel, are you familiar if there is a 3rd party lib that might do that for the common serialization methods (pickle/json/xml/...), maybe with annotation on field/member or what not..